Which nozzle will fill the tank faster (or will they fill at the same rate), assuming that the tank is initially evacuated? for (C-duct -- CD nozzle )
There are two types of nozzles: Convergent duct and Convergent-Divergent nozzle. Both are operated under the same conditions for filling the same tank.
The answer says that the CD nozzle fills the tank faster since it can operate over a wider range of pressure ratios.
My doubt is that both nozzles get choked after a certain pressure ratio. Although the CD nozzle can have supersonic flow through it at a low pressure ratio, the mass flow remains constant after the Mach number reaches 1 at the throat. The same applies to the convergent duct, which also gets choked once the flow reaches Mach 1 at the throat. Now, if we follow the answer given, which states that the CD nozzle can operate over a wide range of pressure ratios, this is also true for the convergent duct. I mean, the convergent duct can still operate at the maximum mass flow condition, which is its choked condition.
So, I think that both nozzles will fill the tank at the same rate.

You talk about "the answer" presumably this is in some article or exam? Can you provide the text of it?

If both are lossless, you are correct. In reality, both will have their own discharge coefficients, and these vary with pressure ratio, usually reduced at higher pressure ratios.  I expect the cd nozzle would have better discharge coefficient in the high pressure ratio regime and similar discharge coefficient in the low pressure ratio regime.  Under these assumptions, the cd nozzle would fill the tank first.
